# csv import missing first character

Tags: php, csv

I try to import a utf8 csv file to my prestashop site. It works good on xampp localhost. But on server if first character is special it miss. for example;

I try to import: "Çocuk çantası"
Result         : "ocuk çantası"

What is the reason of this and how can I solve this?

Server runs on Centos.

Comment: [`Note: Locale setting is taken into account by this function. If LANG is e.g. en_US.UTF-8, files in one-byte encoding are read wrong by this function.`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#refsect1-function.fgetcsv-notes) - See also [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

Comment: No code. I use csv import module. I read something about "setlocale". What should be my "locale" configuration? I write from Turkey and problem is about Turkish characters.

Comment: set the locale to Turkish ('tr_TR')

Comment: Try `var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tr_TR.UTF-8', 'tr_TR', 'tr'));` on the server - if one of them succeeds, you will see which one is correct for the server OS, and you can just pass that as the second arg to `setlocale()` in future.

Comment: I look my configuration with "locale -a" and "tr_TR.UTF-8" is already in list.

Comment: In that case, are you sure the input file is UTF-8? If it's not, the first character may be an invalid unicode sequence and would be ignored if the system is expecting UTF-8 input.

Comment: I am sure, when I backup my site and install on localhost there is no problem with the sama file. Also there is no problem if it is not the first character. Is the seperator important? I use "^" instead of ";" I also tried with ";" problem goes on

Comment: Does this happen for the first character in every row or just the very first character in the file?

Comment: Problem occurs in every row

Comment: I have an idea what the problem may be looking at the PHP source, but I need to investigate further and raise it as a bug. In the meantime, if you generate your file by enclosing the first column in double quotes `"` (which you should do anyway since it's a string ;-) ) I think it will resolve the issue for you.

Comment: To help me track down the problem - is it possible that the file may actually be UTF-16 (or other unicode set) and not UTF-8? Also, can you advise if the first character also goes missing if you read the lines into strings using `fgets()` and `fgetss()` respectively?

Comment: Can you send me a simple utf 8 file which you sure it is correct. And I want to try with this.

Comment: Also var_dump doesn't work on my server. Should I install glibc package?

Comment: @DaveRandom I use "locale" command instead of "locale -a" and the result is; LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
It is wrong I think. I should set it again

Comment: `var_dump()` doesn't work? That sounds like there's something fundamentally wrong with the server. `var_dump()` is part of the PHP core, it doesn't require any external libraries. What version of PHP is the server running, and what are you running on you local machine?

Comment: I write this code to ssh command screen. Maybe I made something wrong:) PHP 5.2.17 on Centos.

Comment: Now I understand my locale is not true. How will I change it? If I write "setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tr_TR.UTF-8');" to ssh command screen will it be enough?

Comment: Can it be about php.ini charset properties? Mine is ;default_charset = "iso-8859-1". Should it be utf-8?